# How do I allow access to file in a subfolder using a .htaccess file?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, cpanel

I wanted to make a new folder with cPanel that is publicly accessible so I inserted some config into .htaccess file. However, when I try to access a file in this folder I get the following permission error:

[image: Screenshot of error message]

The subfolder is called "form_surat".

Below is a screenshot of the contents of my .htaccess file.

[image: Screenshot of my .htaccess file]

Below is a screenshot of my cPanel configuration.

[image: Screenshot of my cPanel configuration]

i don't know anything at all about .htacces
so can you make it simple coding to how accesing file in new subfolder

and this is a subdomain from wordpress

Answer (score 0):

**Options -Indexes** will prevent public browsing of the folder's files by everyone.  Add this line to set a default index file with the following

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

You'll need to create an index.php file.